# How to wrap the IO functions in Lua to prevent the user from leaving X directory

Tags: security, io, lua

How could you wrap the IO functions in Lua to prevent someone from leaving your top level directory.

You place them in "MyDoc" and they have full IO access to everything sub of MyDoc but couldn't for example .. back into the C drive or anywhere else.

Comment: do you mean that your script gives user access to the filesystem via os.execute, via io.open, or something else? What do you mean by "leaving your top level directory", and "you place them", to do what, how? Do they have access to lfs module?

Comment: Basically the IO functions are disabled, but would like to enable them and only allow them to be used inside of the game's directory. 

So they couldn't for example do   file = io.open("c:\myfile.txt") they would be limited to the MyDoc directory and all it's subdirectories

Comment: One idea is to turn the file/path given by user into an absolute path, in case it's relative, then match that against the path that's accessible. You would wrap this as a function over the real `io.open` which gets called only if the input path and sandboxed path matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open up liolib.c. head over to these 3 functions

```
static void opencheck (lua_State *L, const char *fname, const char *mode) {
  LStream *p = newfile(L);
  p->f = fopen(fname, mode);
  if (p->f == NULL)
    luaL_error(L, "cannot open file " LUA_QS " (%s)", fname, strerror(errno));
}

static int io_open (lua_State *L) {
  const char *filename = luaL_checkstring(L, 1);
  const char *mode = luaL_optstring(L, 2, "r");
  LStream *p = newfile(L);
  const char *md = mode;  /* to traverse/check mode */
  luaL_argcheck(L, lua_checkmode(md), 2, "invalid mode");
  p->f = fopen(filename, mode);
  return (p->f == NULL) ? luaL_fileresult(L, 0, filename) : 1;
}


static int io_popen (lua_State *L) {
  const char *filename = luaL_checkstring(L, 1);
  const char *mode = luaL_optstring(L, 2, "r");
  LStream *p = newprefile(L);
  p->f = lua_popen(L, filename, mode);
  p->closef = &io_pclose;
  return (p->f == NULL) ? luaL_fileresult(L, 0, filename) : 1;
}
```

these are the functions you want to edit.

the first one receives the file name as the parameter `fname`, the second and the third
pop it out of the lua stack as the local variable `filename`.

now all you need to do is

1) get your own process path

2) canonize the given file path

3) compare them so that they are the same up until the last slash on both

4) if they are not the same then in `opencheck` use `luaL_error(L,"access denied to %s", fname);`
   in the other two `return luaL_fileresult(L,0,filename);`

Comment: It's much easier just to redefine the required functions in Lua instead of in C.

Comment: will you be able to access the io functions yourself from your own code if you redefine them?

Comment: Sure, just save the original functions in locals and use them in the new definitions.

Comment: Complete agree with @lhf. Keep in mind that modifying the lua source like this means you're using a customized version of lua that differs in behavior from standard lua.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have sandboxed your user environment, so for instance they can't use the builtin "require" or "dofile" or "setatable"? Basically you have to limit the functions they can call to only what you want, and create your own versions of anything you want to control. There are several ways to do this and they each have their pros and cons and nothing is unbreakable, all you can do is up the bar of experience, effort and time required to break your "jail".

This means you have to work at the C API level, but I would not recommend modifying the source unless you are very familiar with it and can easily determine that your modifications aren't easiy breakable. By staying at the C API level, at least other Lua users can help validate the solidity of the sandbox.

You have to figure out a way to enable your code to call Lua builtin without allowing the user to call the builtin. I believe you can store tables in the lua registry, where only the C code can look. It's been a while. Or maybe if you don't put getmetable in user environment, that allows you to call the builtins via metatable but user can't get to them.

For example, from C

- you load the builtins such as io module and save the functions you will wrap (such as open) in a (meta)table table;
- delete the builtin table io from _G so user only has access to the version you created; you've saved the functions you will need for later
- create a global table called io and set its metatable to what you created in step 1, so it defines only functions you want to give access to, such as a function called "open".
- In that function you do whatever filtering you need, before calling the builtin you saved.

The details will make a big difference, and implementation will be different if you use Lua 5.1 vs 5.2, but there are several good articles on sandboxing in Lua on the web (sorry no time to find), take a look and come up with something, then maybe post on Lua user mailing list or SO for pros/cons. ;)